# Transfer value for a string to run function

Tags: javascript, ajax, tostring

I have a function to load

```
function goLocation(val){
        console.log(typeof val);
        console.log(val);
}
```

using ajax to read,transfer to json and insert expecting data inside div. 
my code inside ajax call look like that:

```
x+="<i class='far fa-play-circle' onclick='goLocation(String("+myObj[i].video_id+"))'></i> "
```

but if i click on the element i have a error like:

> movie.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: anes1 is not defined
>       at HTMLElement.onclick (movie.php:1) onclick @ movie.php:1 movie.php:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: anes2 is not defined
>       at HTMLElement.onclick (movie.php:1)

Next try :

```
x+="<i class='far fa-play-circle' onclick='goLocation(String('"+myObj[i].video_id+"'))'></i> "
```

or:

```
x+="<i class='far fa-play-circle' onclick='goLocation("+"'"+myObj[i].video_id+"'"+")'></i> "
```

Gives Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

The problem is that myObj[i].video_id  is a variable without value, i know i have to transfer that object to a string but i don't have a idea how....

Comment: You need additional quotes, otherwise your result is `onclick='goLocation(String(anes1))'` which you can clearly see is wrong. Better still, don't use inline event handlers.

Comment: any idea how to do it? i put in to my question few other trays

Comment: Always look at the output. `onclick='goLocation(String('anes1'))'` is invalid nested quotes, leaving just `goLocation(String(` as your JavaScript, which is an error.

Comment: Rather than putting HTML in a string, consider using DOM APIs like `createElement` and `setAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

When ES6 is an option you can do:

```
x += `<i class="far fa-play-circle" onclick="goLocation('${myObj[i].video_id}')"></i>`
```

Is an option, if not you'll have to escape one of the two types of quotes:

```
x += '<i class="far fa-play-circle" onclick="goLocation(\'' + myObj[i].video_id + '\')"></i>'
```

However solutions creating elements through the DOM API and/or setting events using event listeners might be cleaner.

Comment: for now i transfer data for number so that's gives me existing result. But i will check your solution later on.